# One Facebook Group is most of my wall, can I tweak this?

Tags: facebook

I joined a group a few weeks ago now. It is quite active and ever since, the majority of content on my feed/wall is posts from this group. Often multiple posts in a row.

I like the group but not *that* much. I rarely comment on posts or post reactions - I thought FaceBook would learn to show fewer posts but it isn't.

Can I control how frequently this group's content is shown somehow, without blocking it entirely?

Answer (score -1):

Once you're in FB, in the left hand panel you'll find the Newsfeed icon. Click on the ... (the more option) immediately to the right of the icon. That will bring up the Preferences for your Newsfeed. Scroll down the choices and click "Unfollow people and groups to hide their posts." Then choose the group or person you want to unfollow. (The nice thing about this, is that the group or person is not notified of your action - only you will know). Good luck...